# Do we really need a monsters tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Any objections if we just get rid of [monsters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters)?

A new question today used it and I see it now has a whopping 3 questions, one closed.  Two use [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) and one uses [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy)

It seems redundant to me and should be under [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror).  (Occasionally [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) or [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) might work better, or they could be combined with [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror))

Any interest in keeping [monsters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters) as a synonym of [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)?  My inclination is not to but it would keep people from recreating this unneeded tag.

Comment: [tag:horror] and [tag:fantasy] are genre tags; at a glance, [tag:monsters] seems not, to me (it seems more a story element). So while it's certainly a valid question whether we should have [tag:monsters] at all, they are not *quite* in the same category in my book.

Comment: @aCVn I hear you.  Pretty much every question about monsters though will, or should, have a [tag:horror] tag (the rare exceptions will have another genre tag).  I can't really think of any question about monsters that wouldn't (aside from the colloquial use of "monster").

Comment: Do serial-killers fall into the monster category? 
What do you expect to talk about when you ask about monsters?
Btw, I am 100% in favor of removing tags.  
Following aCVn: monsters could be a sub-category of story-element, maybe.

Comment: @NofP Monsters can mean a horror/fantasy being *or* they can mean bad people/villains.  Not both in one tag please.  So far, this [tag:monsters] tag has been the former.  We already have [tag:antagonists] which covers villains.

Comment: @NofP Unfortunately, there is no way (that I am aware of) within the Stack Exchange ecosystem of having "subtags" or tag hierarchies. It would be a really useful feature for sites like Writing, though.

Answer (score 12):

## Add a wiki and keep the tag

Not being a popular tag should not be ground for deletion. The [three question that use it](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters) are clearly related and no other tag would aptly describe how or why they are related. Additionally there at [66 questions that use the word monster](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=monsters+-%5Bmonsters%5D+is%3Aq) but don't have the tag. I'm sure at least some of them would benefit from it.

Here is a suggestion for the usage guidance:

> For questions about things that go bump in the night. Questions about real or imaginary monstrous creature, how to describe them or incorporate them into works of fiction.

And a tag wiki:

> Monsters are a staple of the [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) and [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) genres, but also appear in [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)'s literature and various other works. From the monster under the bed to the bogeyman, this tag covers any creature that could be described as a monster.
>
> Questions with this tag should focus on the [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative) elements of including a monster in a story, or the physical description of monsters. Questions about creating monsters are off-topic. Some example questions:
>
> - How can I make the monsters in my children's story less scary?
> - How do I make a monstrous character relatable?
> - What are the advantages of keeping the monster unnamed in a horror story?
>
> Related tags: [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)[fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy)[mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)

From those suggestions you should be able to see what I think this tag should be used for. I can see a clear use-case and don't think it needs to be removed.

Comment: You make a good case.  If we keep it then I think your wiki is fantastic.  And you're right, there are a lot of questions out there.  Maybe it is a useful tag...

Comment: @Cyn I have made this tag wiki suggestion now.

Comment: I approved the edit but I think it's like other edits, that it takes two people.

Comment: I agree with linksassin, the tag could be useful. @Cyn, I went ahead and approved the edits.

Comment: I honestly wasn't convinced at all, until I saw the wiki proposal.  Now I am.

Comment: And I found one typo in the approved wiki and fixed it (creature --> creatures).  If I'm wrong, speak up.